Issue in findOne() in mongodb atlas
I am using React and Next.js in my application. When a new user signs up, they go through the payment process and log in with Xero. However, after this step, the application redirects to the wrong condition because the user data isn’t inserted into MongoDB.
During debugging, I added a findOne method to check if the email already exists before inserting the data. Despite using await to handle the asynchronous process and passing only the email to check for existence, the data still isn’t being inserted into MongoDB. After the findOne line, nothing happens—no console logs are printed. However, the odd part is that about 1 out of every 4–5 attempts succeeds in inserting the data.
The table and collection are being fetched correctly, so I’m not sure why this inconsistency is occurring.

If you provide the problematic code, we might be able to help find the problem

To help you, please provide a code sample and at least one of the documents in your collection (you can anonymize both)

Sounds a bit like a race condition.  Check out the docs on Causal Consistency

const trialEnd = addDays(new Date(), 28)
const existingUser = await find({ db: req.db, collection: 'users', find: { email }, limit: 1 })
if (existingUser.data) {
// If user already exists update data
await update({   this is the problmetic code after the trialEnd its not executing any line, and one thing that i have noticed its working fine in local but not working in production ( in my local i am using nodejs 20 but in production i am using nodejs 18) thanks
